# npm vulnerabilities during update

Tags: node.js, npm

I am just started to learn Javascript and node, so probably my question is pretty simple. Whatever I want to do with `npm`, I always get the answer:

```
up to date, audited 71 packages in 4s

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

if I run `npm audit fix`:

```
# npm audit report

tar  <=4.4.17
Severity: high
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite on Windows via insufficient relative path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5955-9wpr-37jh
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning using symbolic links - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9r2w-394v-53qc
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite due to insufficient absolute path sanitization - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3jfq-g458-7qm9
Arbitrary File Creation/Overwrite via insufficient symlink protection due to directory cache poisoning - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r628-mhmh-qjhw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tar
  tar-pack  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of tar
  node_modules/tar-pack
    create-react-app  >=1.3.0-alpha.58689133
    Depends on vulnerable versions of tar-pack
    node_modules/create-react-app

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

Anybody can help me to fix that?

Comment: You are running `npm audit report` instead.

Answer (score 0):

just do the below steps

1. npm audit (this gives you the detailed information about the vulnerabilities)
2. npm audit fix (this tries to fix all these vulnerabilities without causing any errors like if any error breaks changes then it wont update to that new version)
3. npm audit fix -f (this is to be used only in case that you are okay with any breaking changes that can be seen once all packages are updated to latest new versions)